# MobiControl Device Enrollment Profile Installation Failed with "The request timed out"

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi, mobile-device-management

I am trying to enroll my iPad to be a remotely controlled device via SOTI MobiControl. The Wi-Fi is internal and is currently not able to access public IPs. After I tap on Install, it times out after 45 seconds. The error message is:

> **Profile Installation Failed**
>   The request timed out

Does anyone know what the device is trying to do at this point? I am thinking the iPad is trying to communicate with Apple, but I am not sure.

[image: MobiControl Device Enrollment]

[image: Profile Installation Failed - The request timed out]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profile information states that the profile contains a 'device enrollment challenge'. A device enrollment challenge requires connection to a device enrollment server—not Apple's servers, but another server that the payload is informed of.

When you press Install and enter your passcode if appropriate, all the payloads that are contained within a mobile configuration profile are activated. The device enrollment challenge payload attempts to connect to the aforementioned server at this point. It is at this stage that the error shows: "The request timed out". This is to inform you that the server that the payload is attempting to contact is unavailable and the request has timed out.

To fix this, you'll need to allow whatever is preventing the connection to succeed. The problem may not be the device though—the server itself may be unavailable. Unfortunately, a 'request timed out' error is very broad and could be caused by many different reasons, but the basis is that **the server (again, not Apple's) is unavailable to the device requesting the connection**.

Comment: Perhaps a port to the server that will manage this device is blocked?

Comment: @Sun Yes, this could be a reason. The default port for a device enrollment challenge is 8443.

Comment: Hi George. I will ask our network admin to open port 8443 on the server and see if the device can be enrolled.

Answer (score 0):

I have experianced this same issue myself and found that if you connect to the wi-fi of the building that you want to connect to the server of it will connect every time....i hope this helps

Comment: If the server we are connecting to was available to the "wi-fi of the building" and the firewall port is not blocked, then we would be able to do it the way you describe.